# Ошибка mysql 1048: Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть запрос типа:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT 
    vendors_id,
    merchants_id,
    SUM(amount) AS amount,
    SUM(commission_amount) AS commission_amount 
  FROM
    (SELECT 
      vendors_id,
      merchants_id,
      amount,
      commission_amount 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        vendors.id AS vendors_id,
        merchants_id,
        SUM(transactions_cash.amount) AS amount,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash.commission_amount
        ) AS commission_amount 
      FROM
        ibaserver.transactions_cash,
        ibaserver.vendors,
        ibaserver.merchants 
      WHERE transactions_cash.vendors_id = vendors.id 
        AND TIME > 1466680920208 
        AND TIME <= 1466681880067 
        AND merchants_id = merchants.id 
      GROUP BY transactions_cash.merchants_id 
      ORDER BY transactions_cash.merchants_id) a 
    UNION
    ALL 
    SELECT 
      vendors_id,
      merchants_id,
      amount,
      commission_amount 
    FROM
      (SELECT 
        vendors.id AS vendors_id,
        merchants_id,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash_archive.amount
        ) AS amount,
        SUM(
          transactions_cash_archive.commission_amount
        ) AS commission_amount 
      FROM
        ibaserver.transactions_cash_archive,
        ibaserver.vendors,
        ibaserver.merchants 
      WHERE transactions_cash_archive.vendors_id = vendors.id 
        AND TIME > 1466680920208 
        AND TIME <= 1466681880067 
        AND merchants_id = merchants.id 
      GROUP BY transactions_cash_archive.merchants_id 
      ORDER BY transactions_cash_archive.merchants_id) b) s) q
```

когда внутренний запрос

```
      SELECT 
        vendors_id,
        name,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM ....
```

возвращает данные, то результат возвращается успешно. Если же внутренний запрос возвращает все `NULL`:

[image: результат внутреннего запроса]

то весь запрос возвращает ошибку:

```
Error Code: 1048
Column 'vendors_id' cannot be null
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в случае, когда внутренний запрос возвращает все `NULL`, результат был 0?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста запрос полностью.

Comment: Отредактировала пост.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией `COALESCE()`, которая принимает список параметров и возвращает первое не NULL-значение.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(vendors_id, 0),
  name,
  COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) AS amount
FROM ....
```

Если `vendors_id` вернет не NULL-значение, функция вернет его, в противном случае она перейдет ко второму аргументу и вернет 0.